# How to convert irregular date time series to regular one?

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I have a dataframe 'CHARD' that includes a date-time column, followed by a few variables. The date-time column includes an irregular series of dates and times, and I would like to convert it to a continuous, five-minute interval series. So that something like this:

```
29.08.2021 14:51:03
29.08.2021 14:57:09
29.08.2021 15:03:45
```

becomes this:

```
 29.08.2021 14:55:00
 29.08.2021 15:00:00
 29.08.2021 15:05:00
```

Therefore, I would need to round the times forward in time (14:51 becomes 14:55) and fill in the gaps if there is one five-minute increment missing.

Does anyone have a method for doing this?

Thank you for all your help!

Head of the data frame is:

```
 Date_et_heure Pts    Status Erreur Sum
1 2019-02-05 10:37:34 0.2 NEW-BLOCK        0.2
2 2019-02-07 00:00:00 0.0   NEW-DAY        0.2
3 2019-02-08 00:00:00 0.0   NEW-DAY        0.2
4 2019-02-09 00:00:00 0.0   NEW-DAY        0.2
5 2019-02-10 00:00:00 0.0   NEW-DAY        0.2
6 2019-02-11 00:00:00 0.0   NEW-DAY        0.2
```

Answer (score 3):

First, convert to dates to POSIXlt (date-time) format, then use `seq` and `lubridate::ceiling_date` to create the desired sequence:

```r
library(lubridate)

date <-c("29.08.2021 14:51:03","29.08.2021 14:57:09","29.08.2021 15:03:45")
date <- as.POSIXlt(date, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
# [1] "2021-08-29 14:51:03 CEST" "2021-08-29 14:57:09 CEST" "2021-08-29 15:03:45 CEST"

seq(from = ceiling_date(min(date), unit = "5 minutes"), 
    to = ceiling_date(max(date), unit = "5 minutes"), 
    by = "5 min")
# [1] "2021-08-29 14:55:00 CEST" "2021-08-29 15:00:00 CEST" "2021-08-29 15:05:00 CEST"
```

---

Edited question, edited answer. Sequences of 5 minutes using `complete`.

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = " Date_et_heure Pts    Status Erreur Sum
1 2019-02-05 10:37:34 0.2 NEW-BLOCK        0.2
2 2019-02-07 00:00:00 0.0   NEW-DAY        0.2
3 2019-02-08 00:00:00 0.0   NEW-DAY        0.2
4 2019-02-09 00:00:00 0.0   NEW-DAY        0.2
5 2019-02-10 00:00:00 0.0   NEW-DAY        0.2
6 2019-02-11 00:00:00 0.0   NEW-DAY        0.2")


library(lubridate)

df$date <- as.POSIXlt(paste(df$Date_et_heure, df$Pts), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

df %>% 
  mutate(date = ceiling_date(date, unit = "5 minutes")) %>% 
  complete(date = seq(min(date), max(date),
                      by = "5 min"))

# A tibble: 1,601 x 6
   date                Date_et_heure Pts      Status Erreur      Sum
   <dttm>              <chr>         <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
 1 2019-02-05 10:40:00 2019-02-05    10:37:34    0.2 NEW-BLOCK   0.2
 2 2019-02-05 10:45:00 NA            NA         NA   NA         NA  
 3 2019-02-05 10:50:00 NA            NA         NA   NA         NA  
 4 2019-02-05 10:55:00 NA            NA         NA   NA         NA  
 5 2019-02-05 11:00:00 NA            NA         NA   NA         NA  
 6 2019-02-05 11:05:00 NA            NA         NA   NA         NA  
 7 2019-02-05 11:10:00 NA            NA         NA   NA         NA  
 8 2019-02-05 11:15:00 NA            NA         NA   NA         NA  
 9 2019-02-05 11:20:00 NA            NA         NA   NA         NA  
10 2019-02-05 11:25:00 NA            NA         NA   NA         NA  
# ... with 1,591 more rows
```

Comment: Good answer. And to fill the gaps after you will probably need a continuous series like this: 
`seq(lubridate::dmy_hms('29.08.2021 00:00:00'), lubridate::dmy_hms('29.08.2021 23:59:59'), by = '5 min')` to get your end result. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you both for the input. I got the error message: Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number. I checked and the to and from parameters return NA values. Is that normal? I've formatted the sequence accordingly to Posixct class.

Comment: It's difficult to know without your dataset, check if your dates are in the correct format? you can also edit your question with a minimal example of the problem.

Comment: I've pasted the head of the data frame I'm working with. Though I've only worked with the first column of the header (I'm not modifying the data frame yet, I just want to see if I can work with the first column and make it into the desired sequence).

Comment: Your date are not in the same format, so the date conversion does not work anymore. See my edited answer with your new dataset. You have to slightly change the way you convert date.

Comment: So I used this code: df %>% 
        mutate(df$Date_et_heure = ceiling_date(df$Date_et_heure, unit = "5 minutes")) %>%
        complete(df$Date_et_heure = seq(min(df$Date_et_heure), max(df$Date_et_heure), by = "5 min")) The Date_et_heure column already has the date time format I need. So I would need to redefine it. I receive an error message that there is an unexpected '=' after mutate(df$Date_et_heure

Comment: Another issue I get is that R cannot find a minimum and maximum value for the sequence, among my Posixct list of date times...

Comment: Try to convert your Date_et_heure column to a date format. Verify with `class(df$Date_et_heure)`. If it's not, then your code won't work.

Comment: Could it not work with a date time format? If I change the date time format to only date using as.Date(), the hours, minutes and seconds are wrongly coerced. (and apologies for the late response)

Comment: Yes, I meant date-time format.

Comment: So I tried to run the function, and it returns the error message: Error in UseMethod("complete") : 
  no applicable method for 'complete' applied to an object of class "c('POSIXct', 'POSIXt')"

Answer (score 0):

A pure base R solution:

```
dates <- c("29.08.2021 14:51:03","29.08.2021 14:57:09","29.08.2021 15:03:45")

# convert to datetime format
dates <- as.POSIXct(dates, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

# round up to 5 minutes
dates <- as.POSIXct(300*ceiling(as.integer(dates)/300), origin = "1970-01-01 00:00.00")

# create regular series
seq.POSIXt(from = min(dates), to = max(dates), by = "5 mins")
```

Comment: Thank you both for the input. I got the error message: Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number. I checked and the to and from parameters return NA values. Is that normal? I've formatted the sequence accordingly to Posixct class.